# How do I cover the javascript code pattern || {}

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, code-coverage

I am using JSCover running my Jasmine SpecRunner, which inspects a code fragment of the sort:

```
var MyRootObject = MyRootObject || {};
```

My goal is to bring coverage up to 100%, but I am not sure how best to cover this method of initialising the MyRootObject.

This pattern is used at the start of every library javascript file, to ensure that the order in which the files are loaded is unimportant (and the functions and variables inside are $.extend'ed).

The problem basically is that the first and only time this script is loaded in the SpecRunner, it runs only one side of this test, leaving the other path untested.

Comment: I'm confused at this question.  Are you trying to test performance of a piece of code, but want to test the `or` case of the variable assignment?  If so, why not just set `var MyRootObject = false;` and then `var MyRootObject = MyRootObject || {}`?

Comment: While 100% coverage sounds nice it is a waste of time and development effort to cover things like your example. I also don't think that it's possible at all to create a unit test for this unless you can execute this file in a separated environment. If you can, simply assert that `MyRootObject` is undefined before running the script and contains an object, possibly with certain keys, afterwards.

Comment: In our case, we have the public declared API in one javascript file, and then in another file, we have the support functions which extend the main MyRootObject to provide local functions to support the public API (and do the grunt work). Because of these multiple files, they declare the `var MyRootObject = MyRootObject || {}` so that in the wild, the script order doesn't matter. Without wanting to dynamically alter the SpecRunner.html or have multiple versions of SpecRunner.html, I wanted to cover this line. I posted a solution to my problem below which meant a slight rewrite of the main code.

Answer (score 1):

After digging around, I found a solution that works for me, of course, your mileage may vary:

```
var MyRootObject = MyRootObject || {};
$.extend(true, MyRootObject, {...});
```

I have replaced with:

```
var MyRootObject = $.extend(true, MyRootObject, {...});
```

Internally inside JQuery, if the target (MyRootObject) is null or undefined, it automatically assigns the target inside the function to be {}. By using an external library (which I was already using), I no longer have a conditional path I am not following, as this is delegated to the JQuery library.